# SQL query to get rows from two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables with ID and value columns.

I want to union these two tables but if ID exists in second table, I want to discard all same IDs in first table and retrieve only these IDs from second table. How can I create the query for this?

First table:

```
ID    Value
100   1
100   2
101   3
102   4
```

Second table:

```
ID   Value
100  5
100  6
100  7
102  5
```

The result I want to achieve:

```
ID   Value
100  5
100  6
100  7
101  3
102  5
```

I tried to do as suggested but it still returns only values from table 1:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE1_NAME
                +" UNION ALL"
                +" SELECT * FROM " + TABLE2_NAME
                +" WHERE "+id+" NOT IN (SELECT "+id+" FROM "+TABLE2_NAME+ ")";
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
  select id,value from table1 
  union ALL
  select id , value from table2 
  where id not in (select id from table1)
```

edit as suggested by Ormoz :

To use table2's result if both tables have the ids :

```
  select id,value from table2
  union ALL
  select id , value from table1 
  where id not in (select id from table2)
```

My tests:

```
 create table table1 (id int not null, value int not null);

insert into table1 values
 (100,   1),
 (100,   2),
 (101,  3),
 (102,   4);



create table table2 (id int not null, value int not null);

insert into table2 values
(100,  5),
(100,  6),
(100,  7),
(102,  5);


select id,value , 't2' as t from table2
 union ALL
 select id , value, 't1' from table1 
 where id not in (select id from table2);
```

this is the output:

```
# id, value, t
'100', '5', 't2'
'100', '6', 't2'
'100', '7', 't2'
'102', '5', 't2'
'101', '3', 't1'
```

Comment: you should change table1 to table2 to get the desired result because he wants the value of the second table if the id is in both.

Comment: this one still returns values from table 1 and discard table 2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could do the trick?

```
(
    SELECT id, value FROM table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, value FROM table1
) GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved by removing the where clause to first select:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE1_NAME
                    +" WHERE "+id+" NOT IN (SELECT "+id+" FROM "+TABLE2_NAME)
                    +" UNION ALL"
                    +" SELECT * FROM " + TABLE2_NAME;
```

Special thanks to @Tim3880 and @Ormoz =)